# How to exclude the my app screenshots showing recent apps

Tags: android

As per security concern screenshots of my app screen should not be shown in recent apps.
I have tried adding `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in all activities on the manifest file. However, screenshots are shown in recent apps, can some help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`excludeFromRecents` excludes from recents which is not what you need. Try setting `FLAG_SECURE`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,but this logic will stop the user to take the screenshot manually also,I cannot go with this.

Comment: threre's no other solution. If you want to secure your activity then it gets secured. You can't have half-baked screenshot security here.

Comment: we tried with above logic,in recent app no screenshot of the app is shown,and teh same time we are not able to take the screenshot manually if user wants.

Comment: There's no other way at the moment. Either you block ability to take screenshot completely (which includes recents) or not. Judge what is more important to you and how many users would really need to take a screenshot of that activity

Comment: hi,instead of screenshot in recent apps,can we show any other icon

Comment: No, there is recently no way to provide own bitmap/drawable as thumbnail. All you can do is to add `android:icon` to Activity declaration in your manifest.

Comment: thanks,adding the attribute android:excludeFromRecents="true" to all activities in manifest file working fine, app is not shown in recent apps

Comment: Let me comment that this is wrong approach. Removing from recents is more problematic for users who cannot easily get back to the app than preventing screenshots from being taken (which is rarely needed). You can add this as configurable option for your app.

Comment: client is happy with not showing in recent apps,but we have add the android:excludeFromRecents="true in all the activities like <activity ....android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
is there any other way to configure this?